# "security.OCSP.require" in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl

https://blog.torproject.org/blog/detecting-certificate-authority-compromises-and-web-browser-collusion

"Users of Mozilla Firefox that are concerned about this issue should enable security.OCSP.require in the about:config dialog."

How can i enable this feature in Google Chrome?